# How to read the XMLHTTP request body in android

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest, android-webview, http-post

I am working with the web views in android, XMLHTTP requests are sending to the server from my application in the web view, how can i read the HTTP post request body

Answer (score 0):

There are no `WebViewClient`/`WebChromeClient` callbacks for this (the closest is `shouldInterceptRequest` but that only gives you a URL). If the JavaScript is yours use `addJavaScriptInterface` to pass the request body to the Java code.